# putting image on another image in Monodroid

Tags: android, image, layout, xamarin.android, coordinate

I have 2 images. I want to place one image onto other one by determining its coordinates which will be taken from a client. To be more specific, I will get coordinates for my first image from internet and i want to place this image on other one according to these coordinates. I already put these images into same Linear Layout but couldn't give coordinates and place first one onto second. I also used this code part for placing one image:

```
        ImageView iv = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);

        LinearLayout ll = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);

        LinearLayout ly = new LinearLayout(this);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 0.0f);
        p.SetMargins(20, 20, 60, 60);

        ll.AddView(iv,p);
```

but program failed ll.AddView(iv,p); part. Please help me for this problem.

Comment: Do you want to merge the two images? Will you be editing them later or not?

Comment: Is it not easier to change the resource of your first image?

Comment: If a merge mechanism is possible, I may merge them. What I'll do is that I will copy my first image and place copies according to new coordinates. So, they can be merged as long as I can copy my first image.

Comment: Well if they are overlayed and you want to merge them I suggest you use bitmaps. The coordinate system on this is the best if you want to be precise see my example below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you if you are willing to use bitmaps

```
Bitmap mutableBitmap = originalImageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(overlayBitmap, null, new RectF(left, top, right, bottom), null);
```

Here you have your original image in a bitmap. You create a mutable bitmap that can be edited, then you create a canvas from the mutable bitmap, use `RectF` to specify your overlay bitmap drawing parameters and you then simply paint the second bitmap onto the first and set the mutable bitmap back to your `ImageView`